# How many terms can a former vice-president president serve?

Tags: united-states, constitution, vice-president, presidential-term

If a president were to be unable to serve, with the vice-president becoming president, how many terms would they be able to run/serve for?

Say the president is unable to serve 2 years into their term and the vice president steps in. Will they be able to run for 2 full terms after that because they technically haven't had a full term yet?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A vice president who assumes the office of president to finish out a term may serve a maximum of 10 years. If there are two years or less remaining in the term of the president who left office, the vice president may run for two additional terms. If more than two years remaining, the vice-president may run for only one additional term.

[22nd amendment](https://constitutioncenter.org/interactive-constitution/amendments/amendment-xxii):

> However, it is possible for an individual to serve up to ten years as president. The amendment specifies that if a vice president or other successor takes over for a president—who, for whatever reason, cannot fulfill the term—and serves two years or less of the former president’s term, the new president may serve for two full four-year terms.

Comment: As an example of this, Lyndon Johnson was eligible to run for President in 1968; he served a little over a year of JFK's term after JFK's assassination, following by a landslide election in 1964.  That's why [it was a big deal when he announced he wouldn't run.](https://www.history.com/news/lbj-exit-1968-presidential-race)